# Import third party namespace (of a embedded DLL) into XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to import a namespace of a DLL that is embedded to my EXE.
I am using WPFtoolkit for this application so my XAML is accessing the namespace like this:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit" x:Class="Imperium.MainWindow"
        Title="Imperium" Height="435" Width="510" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Icon="pack://application:,,,/ExtFiles/Imp.ico" Closing="Window_Closing" MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown" WindowStyle="None" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Foreground="Black">
```

it works fine with the DLL being copied locally. But I want both DLL's to be embedded in my EXE. One of the two DLL's (WPFToolkit.dll) is no problem because it's not reference in the XAML, so the solution I used (see http://codeblog.larsholm.net/2011/06/embed-dlls-easily-in-a-net-assembly/comment-page-1/#comment-818 is working fine for this one).

However, the second dll (system.windows.controls.datavisualization.toolkit.dll) is giving me trouble.

any idea how I could do this?

thank you
Steve

edit: let me clarify a little more:

My app has 2 DLL's, I was able to embed both in the EXE (the file size shows that's in there), and one of them is being called just fine (only called with using's).

The other is called as a XAML namespace import - and I get an error when I run the program.

Here's my App.g.cs

```
public static void Main() {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += OnResolveAssembly; //aded
            Swiftech_Imperium.App app = new Swiftech_Imperium.App();
            app.InitializeComponent();
            app.Run();
        }

        // added
        private static Assembly OnResolveAssembly(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            Assembly executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName(args.Name);

            string path = assemblyName.Name + ".dll";
            if (assemblyName.CultureInfo.Equals(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == false)
                path = String.Format(@"{0}\{1}", assemblyName.CultureInfo, path);
            using (Stream stream = executingAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(path))
            {
                if (stream == null)
                    return null;
                byte[] assemblyRawBytes = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(assemblyRawBytes, 0, assemblyRawBytes.Length);
                return Assembly.Load(assemblyRawBytes);
            }
        }
```

see the beginning of the post for the XAML.

Both DLL's have their set action to "embedded resource".

I used this "tutorial": http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/61/combining-multiple-assemblies-into-a-single-exe-for-a-wpf-application

I wasn't able to find where to put the XAML (target) that is mentioned in this tutorial, so it's probably why it's not working.

I am using VS Express 2013, it's maybe why I can't find what the author is referring to by:

```
(this code snippet should be added to your project file underneath where the standard Microsoft.CSharp.targets file is imported):
```

Comment: Does anyone have an idea? The DLL is well embedded but unfortunately, part of the XAML that calls it can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late answer, but I just figured it out myself. You need to actually open the project file with an external text editor and paste the stuff provided in your linked tutorial at the end of it.

That should fix your problems.